# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'" in .spec file

Tags: python, pip, kivy, packaging, kivymd

I already did pip install kivymd in my Python project. I also had the kivymd directory in my project.
I'm working with a Mac.
I created a spec file called "coinsnack4.spec" including the code below:

```
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
```

However, when I try to package my python project with the spec file with the command:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed coinsnack4.spec
```

I got the error below:

```
  File "coinsnack4.spec", line 3, in <module>
    from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'
```

I really don't know why this happens because I already pip install kivymd. I don't know what to do next and I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this error.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which IDE, are you using. IDE must be using a different Python interpreter than the one being used on terminal

Comment: Hi! I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: Can you check in the pycharm settings if you are using a different python interpreter

Comment: I'm using a virtualvenv interpreter, but it seems that my terminal is using anaconda.

Comment: Please activate virtualenv on terminal and install kivymd or change your pycharm settings to point to the interpreter your terminal is using by default

Comment: Umm... I'm not actually sure how to check the python interpreter on the terminal. I think Pycharm already set up a (venv) virtual environment for my project once I started coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233372/discussion-between-upchanges-and-alok-raj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why are you facing this issue?

The reason behind this is the concept of virtual environments in python. Each virtual environment is independent of the other. You can use different virtual environments, activate and deactivate them as per your project's requirements.

I would suggest you go through this doc once [Python venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

As when you do a `pip install <SOME_PACKAGE> from your local terminal, it installs the package from into the default python environment and from the terminal itself (not pycharm terminal) if you try to execute the python program it will work fine but as soon as you switch to pycharm or any other IDE, it has it's own python environment set and that environment is unaware of what happened in the other python environment. So you need to install the pip package here also, in order to execute the same python program.

### Solution:-

The first thing I would suggest is to install the package in the virtual environment that the pycharm is using. For that click on the `Terminal` icon the below bar of your pycharm window. then do run the below command :-

```
python3 -m pip install kivymd
```

If this doesn't work, try configuring the python environment in pycharm.

Below is how you can change or update your python interpreter in pycharm: -

### Setting an existing Python interpreter

At any time, you can switch your Python interpreter either using the Python Interpreter selector or in the Project Settings/Preferences.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

[image: 4]

### Creating a new Python interpreter

To add a new interpreter to the current project:
[image: 5]

If you have a conda environment, follow the below steps: -

[image: 6]

Or if you want to setup a new virtual environment, do as below: -

[image: 7]
[image: 8]
[image: 9]

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed pyinstaller not in project's virtualenv, just:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

then problem will be fixed.

Comment: The author created .spec file, so the problem is definitely not in pyinstaller.

Comment: I had the same problem with my project, of course I also created a .spec file for it, but when I run it, I get the same error as above. And I found out that I installed pyinstaller which is outside the 'venv' that I create on my project. So when I reinstalled pyinstaller in venv the problem is fixed.